# Flash site loads slowly

Tags: apache2

I have a simple html page that embeds an swf, that downloads other xml, swf and image files. The total count of the requests reaches about 90. I am aware that it should take a while until the content is available and I am OK with that. All the needed files are hosted by two different providers in the US:
flashxml.net/monochrome-demo.html
and
u1.flashcomponents.net/samples/8751/index.html
From two different countries in Europe, the content shows up a lot later (almost twice as later) from flashxml, than flashcomponents.
I've done mtr tests and the ping difference is about 40ms and the flashxml server load is below 1.

Do you have any other suggestions as to what should I look at?

Comment: 90 HTTP requests are needed to load that page? I don't care what CDN you use, that's gonna have a huge impact on your page loading speed. You need to cut that number down by at least 80%. Are you using CSS sprites? Have you consolidated JavaScripts and CSS files? Are you only downloading content you need? Or are you fetching data that *might* be necessary a fraction of the time?

Comment: I think you've found the problem there. Each load has it's overhead an all those 40ms differences add up.

Comment: I made my comment an answer since it probably is the answer, or darn close to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the problem was the lag between my US server and my location. All those couple of milliseconds added up to seconds with so many requests.
After moving my files to Amazon Cloudfront, the lag decreased considerably and now the loading time is still pretty high, but a lot smaller than before.

In case anyone else find himself in the same situation as I am, he may want to consider using a CDN.

Answer (score 0):

90 HTTP requests are needed to load that page? I don't care what CDN you use, that's gonna have a huge impact on your page loading speed. You need to cut that number down by at least 80%. Are you using CSS sprites? Have you consolidated JavaScripts and CSS files? Are you only downloading content you need? Or are you fetching data that might be necessary a fraction of the time?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Let's just say I can't cut the number of requests. Also the 40 ms ping difference would translate to only about 4 seconds of difference in page load. Unfortunately, the difference is much bigger.
Could you please check out http://flashxml.net/monochrome-demo.html vs http://u1.flashcomponents.net/samples/8751/index.html yourselves?